# jQuery Select classes start with smth

Tags: jquery

in jQuery, for selecting the inputs which their class starts with "`item_number_`" we do:

```
$('input[class^="item_number_"]').on('change', function(){
    // do blah...
})
```

Now, I want the above function but also applied to the new inputs appended to the page via jQuery, so:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[class^="item_number_"]', function(){
    // do blah
})
```

but the second code is not working :-(

what's the solution?

Comment: your "second code is not working" is `undefined`

Comment: seems fine to me, can you paste your html with newly appended inputs ?

Comment: @AmitJoki what do you mean?

Comment: It means your dynamic inputs don't have a class starting with `item_number_`.

Comment: I mean to say, how is it not working?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work for me !

http://jsfiddle.net/s37Mg/2/

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#form').append($('<input>', {
        'type': 'text',
        'class': 'item_number_2'
    }));
}, 2500);

$(document).on('change', 'input[class^="item_number_"]', function(e) {
    console.log('change', $(this).attr('class'), $(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Check your console and make sure there isn't an error before this. Here is a demo of it working: http://jsbin.com/likehuda/1/edit?html,js,output